# my huawei modem is detected as unknown device

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem, huawei

My Huawei EC156 (Sudani) is detected as unknown device in Ubuntu 14.04
, when I'm trying to create a new mobile broadband connection in device selection step it shows (any device) instead of (Huawei technology ....).
when I choose (any device) and create the connection it disconnects every minute
please help